# How to make "tcolorbox" adjust to width of text it contains and respect the text's line breaks at the same time?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, line-breaking, tcolorbox, width

This is my code:

```
\begin{tcolorbox}
this is line 1\\
\hspace*{5mm}this is line 2
\end{tcolorbox}
```

This is the code's output (red line is where the right side of the box should've been if it were automatically adjustable to the text size):

[image]

If I specify [hbox] option, it adjusts automatically but ignores the text's line breaks (which I need to keep).

Comment: Use a tabular for the content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does `tikznode` option do what you want?

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\begin{document}

\tcbox[tikznode={align=left}]{%
this is line 1\\ \hspace*{5mm}this is line 2}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @bp2017 default alignment is `center` (use `\tcbox[tikznode]{...}`) . I think you don't need to much `tikznode` options because it's only used for the text, the surrounding box is drawn by tcolorbox.